# VBA Change position of all images in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to set all images to right side, and wrap the text.

[image]

so, that it appear likes.

[image]

```
Sub convert()
    Dim shap As InlineShape, shapa As Shapes, sh As Shape
    For Each shap In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        shap.Select
        Selection.Fields.Unlink
        With Selection
            .WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = True
            .WrapFormat.Side = wdWrapBoth
            'Selection.Fields.Unlink
        End With
    Next shap
    For Each shap In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        shap.Select

        shap.ConvertToShape

    Next shap

    ActiveDocument.Shapes.SelectAll

    With Selection
        .ShapeRange.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTopBottom
        .ShapeRange.Top = wdShapeTop
        .ShapeRange.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTopBottom
        .ShapeRange.Left = wdShapeRight
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work.

```
Sub convert()
Dim shap As InlineShape, shapa As Shapes, sh As Shape
For Each shap In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    shap.Select
    Selection.Fields.Unlink
    Set sh = shap.ConvertToShape
    With sh
        .Left = wdShapeRight
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
        .WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = True
        .WrapFormat.Side = wdWrapLeft
    End With
Next shap
End Sub
```

One thing that can be tricky about inlineshapes/shapes is that you really should set a new variable for the shape, otherwise you'll get errors when using shape's properties on a variable that is of type inlineshape.